# How to retrieve reference field's value dynamically

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, schema

```
sObject record = Database.query(query); // current record values 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType objSchema = schemaMap.get(objName); sent from aura controller.
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = objSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String fieldName: fieldsList) { // List of field api names to query in List<String>
    if(result != ''){
        result += ',';
        Object recValue = record.get(fieldName) != null ? record.get(fieldName) : '';
        String jsonPart = '{';
        jsonPart += '"label":"' + fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel() + '",';
        jsonPart += '"name":"' + recValue + '"';
        jsonPart += '}';
        result += jsonPart;
    }
}
return '['+result+']'; //returning json with field label as key and field value as name
```

Now my "fieldList" list contains "AccountId,Account.Name" in it. But when I try to retrieve the value of Account.Name, I'm facing "Attempt to dereference null object" exception. Can anyone share an idea/solution on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use faux JSON encoding, you're asking for trouble. In addition, if you have something like Account.Name, you need to do some dynamic logic. Something like:

```
Object getValueFromPath(sObject record, String path) {
  String pathParts = path.split('\\.'); // Regex needs escaping
  while(pathParts.size() > 1 && record != null) {
    record = record.getSObject(pathParts.remove(0));
  }
  Object result = record?.get(pathParts[0]);
  if(result == null) {
    result = '';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Similarly, you need to go through the path dynamically for the label:

```
String getLabelFromPath(sObjectType sType, String path) {
  String[] pathParts = path.split('\\.');
  while(pathParts.size() > 1 && sType != null) {
    String part = pathParts.remove(0);
    // Custom relationships
    String partId = part.endsWith('__r')? part.removeEnd('__r')+'__c': part;
    sType = sType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(partId)?.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()[0];
  }
  return sType;
}
```

As for forming your JSON, you should write something like this:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for(String field: fieldList) {
  results.add(new Map<String, Object> {
    'label' => getLabelFromPath(record.getSObjectType(), field),
    'name' => getValueFromPath(record, field)
  });
}
return JSON.serialize(results);
```

Comment: thanks sfdcfox. It worked. One small addition to your code in this line. Instead of "String partId = part.endsWith('__r')? part.removeEnd('__r')+'__c': part;", I made it to "String partId = part.endsWith('__r')? part.removeEnd('__r')+'__c': part+'Id';"